# $(this).attr("data-id") returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a webshop and on every item there is a button to add that item to the shopping cart.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$path = "../images/women/winter/winter1";
$lang = "description_".get_param();

if(!$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cloths;")){
die("There was an error running the query [".$db->error."]");
}
while($winter = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<div class = \"boxsale $winter[image]\">
              <img src = \"$path.jpg\"/>
              <div class = \"test\"> $winter[$lang] </div>
              <select>
                <option>S</option>
                <option>M</option>
                <option>L</option>
                <option>XL</option>
                <option>XXL</option>
              </select>
              <button class = \"addToCart\" onclick = \"executeJS()\"> <i class = \"fa fa-shopping-cart\" data-id = \"$i\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></button>
      </div>";
      $i++;
  }?>

</div>
```

when you click on the button the executeJS() in the last few lines gets called from a seperate file.

**addToCart.js**

```
function executeJS(){
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    url: "ajax.php?id=" + id + "&action=add"
  })
  .done(function(){
    alert("Product has been added.");
  });
}
```

i wanted to grab the data-id from the button that has been clicked, with

`$(this).attr("data-id");` but all i get is a header that has *undefined* as data-id.

```
id=undefined&action=add
```

can anyone please point me in the right direction?

thanks

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your PHP. Post a [mcve] please, including the *rendered* HTML. Also, your buttons don't have a data attribute but their fontawesome `<i>` children do

Comment: You can try and use the Vanilla JavaScript notation 

`this.dataset.id`

Comment: because when you use inline events, `this` is the `window` object.

Comment: var id = $(this).find("i").attr("data-id");

Comment: Are you sure `this` is what you think it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because `$(this)` is not correctly being applied to the element you're trying to access. When using a string based onclick handler (`onclick="test()"`), `this` refers to the window, and **NOT** the element you're trying to access.

```js
function test() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="test" onclick="test()" data-id="test">Link</a>
```

If you want to use the string based onclick notation, pass your element in explicitly, and do `$(element)`.

```
<button class = \"addToCart\" onclick = \"executeJS(this)\" data-id = \"$i\" />
```

Javascript:

```
function executeJS(element){
    var id = $(element).data('id');
    ...
```

Personally, skip the attr-id all together, and simply pass your id directly:

```
<button class = \"addToCart\" onclick = \"executeJS($id)\" />
```

Comment: thank you, it works just fine and it's much simpler to pass over the id directly

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `this` may be pointing to the window instead of the button.

You can fix this by manually looking for the button:

```
var id = $(".addToCart").attr("data-id");
```

This will only really work if you only have one button. What you *should* do is use jquery to attach the event to the button.

In your javascript:

```
$(".addToCart").click(function(e){
    var id = $(e.target).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.php?id=" + id + "&action=add"
    })
    .done(function(){
        alert("Product has been added.");
    });
})
```

The e.target refers to the button that is being clicked.

Comment: Good concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use **regular function** (`function(){}`) instead of arrow function:

```
$(document).on("click",".deleteBtn",function(){
    //Your Code
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using jQuery, this is how you should be doing it. First, remove the inline event handler in your PHP (e.g. `onclick = \"executeJS()\"`)

The other issue is that your buttons don't have a data attribute but their `<i>` children do.

Next, create your jQuery event handler, binding to the button. By doing this you can use `$(this).find('i')` to get the fontawesone `<i>` element and its data attribute, `.attr("data-id")`:

```
$('button.addToCart').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('i').attr("data-id");
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajax.php?id=" + id + "&action=add"
    })
    .done(function() {
      alert("Product has been added.");
    });
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/m6b2eanv/)**

Comment: Anonymous coward downvoter care to comment? I love it when someone is wrong, *and* doesn't have the cojones to explain their downvote.

Comment: i like this so far the most. but google dev tools apparently don't. it works fine in JSfiddle but i get an Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, when i run it

Comment: @PhilippeLeiser What do you mean?